# org.apache.derby.client.am.CloseFilterInputStream

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Sr I am new with derby, When I try to test display a Blob field in database, and this display "org.apache.derby.client.am.CloseFilterInputStream" .

```
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    for (Images o : IM.getAllImages()) {
        InputStream is = o.getImg();
        byte[] imageBytes = getBytes(is);
        out.write(imageBytes);
        response.setContentLength(imageBytes.length);
        response.getOutputStream().write(imageBytes);
        out.close();
    }
```

Also, when i try this code,This error come up "java.io.IOException: The object is already closed.". Do I missing something ?
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JySjq.png)

This is Method to covert InputStream to byte array

```
    public static byte[] getBytes(InputStream is) throws IOException {

    int len;
    int size = 1024;
    byte[] buf;

    if (is instanceof ByteArrayInputStream) {
        size = is.available();
        buf = new byte[size];
        len = is.read(buf, 0, size);
    } else {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        buf = new byte[size];
        while ((len = is.read(buf, 0, size)) != -1) {
            bos.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        buf = bos.toByteArray();
    }
    return buf;
}
```

My doGet 
DisplayImagesController.java

```
    @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    for (Images o : IM.getAllImages()) {
        InputStream is = o.getImg();
        byte[] imageBytes = getBytes(is);
        out.write(imageBytes);
        response.setContentLength(imageBytes.length);
        response.getOutputStream().write(imageBytes);

    }
    out.close();
}
```

and Display

```
        <table width="70%" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>IMG</th>
            <th>IMG Name</th>
            <th>UserID</th>

            <th colspan="2">Action</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${imgs}" var="img">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${img.id}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${img.imgName}"/></td>
                <td><img src="DisplayImagesController" width="200" height="100"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${img.userID}"/></td>

            </tr>
        </c:forEach>

    </table>
```

But the images dont display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        for (Images o : IM.getAllImages()) {
            InputStream is = o.getImg();
            byte[] imageBytes = getBytes(is);
            out.write(imageBytes);
            response.setContentLength(imageBytes.length);
            response.getOutputStream().write(imageBytes);

        }
out.close();
```

i think `out.close();` should be out side the `for-each` loop because, if you have multiple image then it may not create another out object.

Comment: Even if i set 'out.close();' out side the loop, the images don't display ?